# Error when sending purchase order e-mail in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

[image: Error Payment Vindi]
Magento 2.3 is recognizing as a wrong route when sending the email, it also happens when making the purchase by the store. The process with Vindi works perfectly, there is only the detail of sending the email with the expected information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by copying the folder from the **adminhtml/templates/info/cc.phtml** to the **frontend/templates/info/cc.phtml**